# What OLAP features are in BigQuery?

Tags: olap, google-bigquery

In the BigQuery documentation it is mentioned that it uses OLAP functions. But the developer documentation does not mention MDX query language, dimension or fact tables. What OLAP features, if any, are in BQ and how are they

Answer (score 4):

BigQuery is not a traditional OLAP system. The similarity to OLAP is in its ability to rapidly answer multi-dimensional queries. There are no cubes or star/snowflake schema that one might find in a traditional OLAP system. Instead BigQuery excels at ad hoc queries, usually over a large flattened table. If you can share your use case, others on this forum may be able to suggest some best practices to accomplish your goal using BigQuery.

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery is OLAP. It is a ROLAP, not MOLAP as SSAS.
SQL with analytical functions.

Answer (score -2):

I am agreeing with Andrew. No OLAP process, no MDX or similar, just sql and no integration in google spreadsheet !
I don't think that business users will use big query as an olap system, let's say that it is a cloud access like DB, that is good

Comment: much has changed since that moment